# Validate that value is unique over multiple tables access

Tags: validation, database-design, unique

**Scenario:** I have to create a database which has to contain 3 different tables holding information about people. Lets call them Members, Non_Members and Employees. Among the other information they may share , one is the telephone number. The phone numbers are unique, each in its respective table.

**My problem:** I want to make sure the phone number is always unique among these 3 tables. Is there a way to create a validation rule for that ? If not and I need to redesign the database, which would be the recommended way to do it.

**Additional info:** While the 3 tables hold the same information (Name , address etc.) its not required always required to fill them. So I am not sure if a generic table named Persons would work for my case.

**Some ideas:** I was wondering if and how I can use a query as a validation rule (that would make things easier). If I would end up creating a table called Phone numbers , how would the relations between the 4 tables would work in order to ensure that each of the 3 tables has a phone number.

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdBt2.jpg)

Comment: Can an employee also be a member?

Comment: Well I took the liberty of deciding that "no they are not" since there was no mention of it.

Comment: If this is a professional job--not a homework assignment--that's a relatively risky decision.

Comment: Its a homework assignment

Comment: In any case I used access macros to check the other table ( I am using two tables holding phones) and prevent or allow the update/add of a record. Seemed to work ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a relational database.

I would go for a single `person` table with a "type" column (member, non_member, ...). That is much more flexible in the long run. It's easy to add new "person types" - what if you later want a "guest" type?

You would need to define as nullable to cater for the "not all information is required" part.

With just a single table, it's easy to make the phone number unique.

If you *do* need to make it unique across different tables, you need to put the phone numbers in their own table (where the number is unique) and the references that `phone_number` table from the other tables.

**Edit**

Here is an example of creating such a `phone_number` table:

```
create table phone_number 
(
   id integer primary key, 
   phone varchar(100) not null unique
);

create table member 
(
   id integer primary key, 
   name varchar(100), 
   ... other columns
   phone_number_id integer references phone_number
);
```

The tables `non_member` and `employee` would have the same structure (which **is** a strong sign that they should be a single entity)

**Edit 2** (2016-01-08 20:12)

As sqlvogel correctly pointed out, putting the phone numbers into a single table doesn't prevent a phone number to be used by more than one person (I misunderstood the requirement so that no phone number should be stored more than once)

Comment: Would it help for you to better understand my scenario if I added my erd ?

Comment: @DimosFotiadis: help for what?

Comment: I agree with your first suggestion but because this database is for a school project I am not sure what you say in your second paragraph would be accepted =/ . If I am to make a table named phone numbers how would it work exactly. Would I have to add the phone number in the table [phone number] and then include a field with a drop down list populated from the [phone number] table , in each for the tables?

Comment: Actually would I need a one to one relation between [phone numbers] and the 3 other tables?

Comment: I will probably go with the reference thing you propose. But lets say I go and make them a single entity like they are in my ERD (PERSONS) how would I handle the relations for the extra attributes as shown in the ERD

Comment: @DimosFotiadis: with Postgres you could use table inheritance, with other DBMS you just create additional table that reference `person` with one-to-zero/one relationship

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time , I went ahead and made a persons table with one to one and seems to be working for me.

Comment: oh something extra in the ERD would the symbol "IS A" still be applicable ? Or do I need to change it into a relations symbol ?

Comment: How does creating a separate phones table ensure that no phone number is used more than once across all three referencing tables? It does not accomplish that as far as I can see and therefore does not answer the question.

Comment: @sqlvogel: hmm, I didn't read it as "should never be used more than once" - but of course you are right. This model would not prevent that.

Comment: At the end I decided to do that with a macro in Access , two tables clients, employees and a macro searching the other table for the phone and prevents the update / creation of the record.  It should do the work ^^ Thanks a lot for the help and sorry for the late reply.